# tangent line vs secant line

Tags: calculus

According to definition, secant lines intersect the curve on two different points say $P,Q$ while tangent lines intersect only at one point. Also according definition with $P$ fixed and $Q$ variable as $Q$ approaches $P$ along the curve direction of secant approaches that of tangent.

Now my question is if is curve like sine curve then can we find a tangent line on arbitrary point if so i guess it will contradict the definition of tangent line that it only intersect only a single point of the curve

Please help 
Ahsan

Comment: The number of intersections is a *local* condition.  A line is the tangent line to a curve at the point $P = (x, y)$ if there is an interval (possibly very small) around $x$ such that the line only intersects the curve once *in this interval.*  The tangent line can intersect the curve arbitrarily often in other places.

Comment: What about $f(x)=x^2\sin\left(\frac1x\right)$ (with its discontinuity filled in) at the origin? The $x$-axis is a tangent line, because it has the right slope, and the difference between the function and it shrinks faster than any linear function. However, there's no interval on which it only intersects the curve once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The definition of tangent is not that it just intersects at one point. It has to do with precisely the way the line touches the curve at that point, and nothing to do with what happens anywhere else.

If you zoom in closer and closer to the point of tangency, and as you get closer, the curve and the line become indistinguishable, then it's a tangent line. It doesn't matter how many times it might contact the curve at other points, as long as it matches at the point we're interested in.

Comment: then what is difference between secant lines and tangent lines

Comment: If you zoom in close to where the secant line meets the function, it looks like two lines crossing, or something other than two copies of the same line.

Answer (score 1):

If it were correct to define the concept of tangent line by saying it's a line that intersects a curve at only one point, then the $y$-axis would be a tangent line to the curve $y=x^2$.  That is absurd.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a precise geometric definition, you may find the following definition interesting. The intuition is that "near the point of tangency, a tangent line is the closest line to the curve". I learned this definition from a textbook by Jingzhong Zhang (张景中) quite a few years ago. Below is the precise definition.

Line $l$ is tangent to curve $C$ at point $P$, if for any other line $l'$, there exists a open neighbourhood of $P$, denoted $N_\varepsilon(P)$, such that for any point $P_0 \in C \cap N_\varepsilon(P)$ (the curve inside the neighbourhood), the distance from $P_0$ to $l$ is smaller than the distance from $P_0$ to $l'$.

For simplicity, we can use a circle as the open neighbourhood, i.e., $N_\varepsilon(P) = \{ X \mid |XP| < \varepsilon \}$ where $|AB|$ is the length of the line segment $AB$.

Below is a graph for the intuition.

[image: Illustration]

This definition addresses that tangency is a local property (the neighbourhood), and therefore makes it possible to find a tangent line for the sine curve. It also immediately rules out the $y$ axis ($l : x = 0$) as a tangent line of the parabola $C : y = x^2$ (although there is only a single common point between $l$ and $C$, $l$ is apparently not "close enough" to $C$).